# Razor behaving strangely?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, razor, partial-views

Razor is playing tricks with me. I have a partial view:

```
@model ManageMvc.Models.Default.Classes.MvcModule           
@{
    if (Model.CanExpand)
    {
        Response.Write("Crazy");
        @:TEST
        <text>ojiiojjiojiojiojiojiojiojio</text>
        Response.Write("Crazy2");
    }
    else
    {
        Response.Write("Crazy");
        @:TEST
        <text>ssssssssdffffffff</text>
        Response.Write("Crazy2");
    }
}
```

This is called from this:

```
@if (Model.Modules.Count > 0)
{
    for (var i = 0; i < Model.Modules.Count; i++)
    {
        Html.Partial("~/Views/UserControls/_MenuItem.cshtml", Model.Modules[i]);
    }
    ....
}
```

I expected razor to print out whats written inside the Text block and the @: block. But i get nothing. When i run this it just prints CrazyCrazy2 (for each module in the list).
Did i miss something?

**Updated**

The code that is calling if (Model.Modules.Count >  0) is a partial itself. That one is called from the layout page. So the top code is the second partial being called. Can this make any difference?

Layout -> MainMenu (partial) -> CreateMenuItem (partial)

**Updated**

This is the new code: (_MenuItem.cshtml inside Shared->DisplayTemplates)

```
@model ManageMvc.Models.Default.Classes.MvcModule          
@{
    if (Model.CanExpand)
    {
        @:TEST
        <text>ojiiojjiojiojiojiojiojiojio</text>
    }
    else
    {
        @:TEST
        <text>ssssssssdffffffff</text>        
    }
}
```

Partial view MainMenu that is calling the menu item:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Modules, "_MenuItem")
```

Now this breaks on that line and i get the following error:

The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ManageMvc.Models.Default.Classes.MvcModule]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'ManageMvc.Models.Default.Classes.MvcModule'.

Comment: You shouldn't use `Response.Write` as it is outside of the razor engine. Razor writes everything to a StringBuilder and *then* writes it to the Response. So your Crazy Text will output first. Based on a quick test it works jsut fine so I'd gather that your `Models.Modules.Count` always equals 0.

Comment: Hmm...except that it still prints your `Crazy`...

Comment: Thats the problem. First i tried this without the Response.Write but that printed nothing. I know for a fact that there is 2 objects in the Modules. I know that both trigger that code statement. If i remove the Response.Write i get nothing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put an `@` when calling the `Html.Partial` helper and avoid using `Response.Write` in an ASP.NET MVC view:

```
for (var i = 0; i < Model.Modules.Count; i++)
{
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/UserControls/_MenuItem.cshtml", Model.Modules[i]);
}
```

Also instead of writing some ugly loops I would strongly suggest you using templated helpers. So replace the for loop in your layout with this simple helper:

```
@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Modules)
```

and then define the display template (`~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/MvcModule.cshtml`) which will be rendered for each element of the `Modules` collection:

```
@model ManageMvc.Models.Default.Classes.MvcModule           
@if (Model.CanExpand)
{
    @:TEST
    <text>ojiiojjiojiojiojiojiojiojio</text>
}
else
{
    @:TEST
    <text>ssssssssdffffffff</text>
}
```

See how easier this is?

Comment: When i try that i get an error "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[ManageMvc.Models.Default.Classes.MvcModule]', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'ManageMvc.Models.Default.Classes.MvcModule'.". Modules is a list of MvcModules. Also, how can i pass to the DisplayFor template that this is the first item (thus needing another css class) ?

Comment: @Patrick, don't write any `for` loops. Only `@Html.DisplayFor(x => x.Modules)`. And `MvcModule.cshtml` should be strongly typed to `MvcModule`.

Comment: I updated my question with the code that i wrote. I need to have multiple files that servers MvcModule depending on what index in the list the module is located. If its the first/last item it needs some special CSS tags.

Comment: @Patrick, OK, now I understand the problem. You are passing a second argument to the DisplayFor helper which is the name of the template. Unfortunately this doesn't work with collections. The framework wouldn't automatically invoke the editor template for each element of the collection but will directly pass the collection thus the error. To make it work move `_MenuItem.cshtml` to `~/Views/Shared/DisplayTemplates/MvcModule.cshtml` and remove the second argument of the DisplayFor call exactly as shown in my answer. Conventions need to be respected.

Comment: Can i then somehow pass extra information to that template? I need to specify what position it has in the list (needed to print the correct css classes).